# Как вернуть из хранимой процедуры список записей?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Ка создать хранимую процедуру, которая бы запрашивала данные из таблицы без параметров и/или по какому-то параметру и возвращала список записей?

При этому вызов процедуры можно было бы сделать через call, чтобы проверить:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_ALL_EMPLOYEES 
IS
BEGIN
 SELECT *  from  EMPLOYEES ;
END GET_ALL_EMPLOYEES;
```

> Procedure GET_ALL_EMPLOYEES compiled
>
> LINE/COL  ERROR
>   --------- ------------------------------------------------------------- 4/2
>   PLS-00428: в этом предложении SELECT ожидается фраза INTO Errors:
>   check compiler log

```sql
call get_all_employees();
```

> Procedure GET_ALL_EMPLOYEES compiled
>
> LINE/COL  ERROR
>   --------- ------------------------------------------------------------- 7/1
>   PLS-00103: Встретился символ "CALL"  Errors: check compiler log

Вот такой вариант :

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE TESTPRGTWO
IS
L_CUR SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN

open l_cur FOR select * from  employees;

END;
```

Это не работает.

```sql
SELECT OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE, STATUS 
FROM USER_OBJECTS
WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE';
```

В консоли вижу только

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```sql
call TESTPRGTWO();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто может подсказать, как это все сделать?

**Обновление**

A вот как делается в MySQL:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**обновление_2**

А вот какое громоздкое решение и это только полей 4, а бывает по 30 и более, 
и что делать?

```sql
-- Меняем схему  на свою
-- 1 Cоздаем объект с перечислением необходимых полей, которые должны быть выведены из выбираемой таблицы.
--DROP TYPE OBJ_EMPL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJ_EMPL AS OBJECT
(
employeeID NUMBER(19,0),
address  VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
first_Name    VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
last_Name    VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)

);

-- 2 создаем коллекцию объектов - таблицу, из полей ранее определенного типа OBJ_EMPL. Данная таблица появляется в момент
-- вызова переменной LIST_OBJ_EMPL и создается на основе полей, которые были объявлены в ранее созданном типе OBJ_EMPL.
--DROP TYPE LIST_OBJ_EMPL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE LIST_OBJ_EMPL IS TABLE OF OBJ_EMPL;

-- 3 создаем функцию, чтобы возратить результат.
-- getListEmployees - название функции
--  LIST_OBJ_EMPL - тип переменной в которую будет записан результат выборки (может писаться много строк)
-- varObjEmpl - имя локальной переменной, а LIST_OBJ_EMPL - это тип объявленной локальной переменной
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getListEmployees RETURN LIST_OBJ_EMPL IS

varObjEmpl LIST_OBJ_EMPL;

-- начинается выполнение команды
BEGIN
   SELECT OBJ_EMPL ( -- После селекта указывается сам объект, с перечислением полей. То есть мы указываем, что нужно обратиться к типу OBJ_EMPL,
   -- в котором мы перечислили поля (которые нужно вернуть из  таблицы)
   employeeID,
   first_Name,
   last_Name,
   address
   )
        --- большое количество (данных) собирается в указанную ранее локальную переменную, которая имеет ссылку на тип LIST_OBJ_EMPL
        BULK COLLECT INTO varObjEmpl
        FROM EMPLOYEES; -- указывается, из какого объекта будет произведена выборка полей

   RETURN varObjEmpl; -- вернули в точку вызова полученные записи из таблицы
   EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       return NULL;
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
       -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
       RAISE;
END getListEmployees;
/

-- Вызов функции
--SELECT * FROM TABLE(getListEmployees);


-- Создание таблицы
/*

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES
   (EMPLOYEEID NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    ADDRESS VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
    CONSTRAINT PK_EMPLOYEEID PRIMARY KEY (EMPLOYEEID)
     );

     */
```

вызов функции вот такой

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE(getListEmployees);
```

Кто может подсказать, как это все сделать, как упростить  и сделать процедуру, но не функцию?

Comment: А куда вы хотите вернуть результаты и в каком виде ? То как вы расписали невозможно в принципе. Хранимая процедура может возвращать либо курсор для его последующего чтения, либо строки в виде объекта через pipeline для последующего чтения в виде select * from table(PROCEDURE)

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

По порядку с самого простого, которое в вопросе:

> вот такой вариант: [...] PROCEDURE TESTPRGTWO [...] Это не работает.

Не работает потому, что результат надо вернуть. С версии 12.1 будет доступна [dbms_sql.return_result](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm#CIHIICAG), а пока, не на много сложнее, так:

```
create or replace type numList is table of number
/
create or replace procedure testprgtwo (ids numList, rc out sys_refcursor) is
begin
    open rc for 
        select employee_id, first_name, last_name 
        from hr.employees e
        join table (ids) t on t.column_value = e.employee_id
        order by 1;
end;
/
```

Получить результат:

```
set autoprint on
var rc refcursor
exec testprgtwo (numList(191,199), :rc);

EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME                
----------- -------------------- -------------------------
        191 Randall              Perkins                  
        199 Douglas              Grant
```